# How to analyse the trace file generated by ns2 using Visual Trace Analyser?

Tags: ns2

When i open a .tr file in NS-Visual-Trace-Analyser, it shows the all statistics and graphical results. But, when i add energy model to the nodes of the same network, Visual-Trace-Analyser shows no packet sent or received (not any event).

This is Tcl script i am trying..

```
`# This script is created by NSG2 beta1

 #===================================
 #     Simulation parameters setup
 #===================================
 set val(chan)   Channel/WirelessChannel ;# channel type

 set val(prop)   Propagation/TwoRayGround;# radio-propagation model

 set val(netif)  Phy/WirelessPhy    ;# network interface type

 set val(mac)    Mac/802_11         ;# MAC type

 set val(ifq)    Queue/DropTail/PriQueue;# interface queue type

 set val(ll)     LL                 ;# link layer type

 set val(ant)    Antenna/OmniAntenna;# antenna model

 set val(ifqlen) 50                 ;# max packet in ifq

 set val(nn)     2                  ;# number of mobilenodes

 set val(rp)     DSDV               ;# routing protocol

 set val(x)      968                ;# X dimension of topography

 set val(y)      450                ;# Y dimension of topography

 set val(stop)   20.0               ;# time of simulation end 

 set opt(energymodel) EnergyModel   ;

 set opt(initialenergy) 30  ;

 #===================================
 #        Initialization        
 #===================================

 #Create a ns simulator

 set ns [new Simulator]

 #Setup topography object

 set topo       [new Topography]

 $topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)

create-god $val(nn)

#Open the NS trace file

set tracefile [open twonodes.tr w]

$ns trace-all $tracefile

#Open the NAM trace file

set namfile [open twonodes.nam w]

$ns namtrace-all $namfile

$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)

set chan [new $val(chan)];#Create wireless channel

#===================================
#     Mobile node parameter setup
#===================================
$ns node-config -adhocRouting  $val(rp) \

            -llType        $val(ll) \

            -macType       $val(mac) \

            -ifqType       $val(ifq) \

            -ifqLen        $val(ifqlen) \

            -antType       $val(ant) \

            -propType      $val(prop) \

            -phyType       $val(netif) \

            -channel       $chan \

            -topoInstance  $topo \

            -agentTrace    ON \

            -routerTrace   ON \

            -macTrace      ON\

            -movementTrace OFF \

            -energyModel $opt(energymodel) \

            -idlePower 1.0 \

            -rxPower 1.0 \

            -txPower 2.0 \

            -sleepPower 0.001 \

            -transitionPower 0.2 \

            -transitionTime 0.005 \

            -initialEnergy $opt(initialenergy)

$ns set WirelessNewTrace_ ON

#===================================
#        Nodes Definition        
#===================================
#Create 2 nodes

set n0 [$ns node]

$n0 set X_ 383

$n0 set Y_ 309

$n0 set Z_ 0.0

$ns initial_node_pos $n0 20

set n1 [$ns node]

$n1 set X_ 568

$n1 set Y_ 350

$n1 set Z_ 0.0

$ns initial_node_pos $n1 20

#===================================
#        Generate movement          
#================================

#===================================
#        Agents Definition        
#===================================
#Setup a UDP connection

set tcp2 [new Agent/TCP]

$ns attach-agent $n0 $tcp2

set sink3 [new Agent/TCPSink]

$ns attach-agent $n1 $sink3

$ns connect $tcp2 $sink3

$tcp2 set packetSize_ 1500


#===================================
#        Applications Definition        
#===================================
#Setup a CBR Application over UDP connection

set cbr1 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]

$cbr1 attach-agent $tcp2

$cbr1 set packetSize_ 1000

$cbr1 set rate_ 1.0Mb

$cbr1 set random_ 

$ns at 1.0 "$cbr1 start"

$ns at 20.0 "$cbr1 stop"


#===================================
#        Termination        
#===================================
#Define a 'finish' procedure

proc finish {} {

    global ns tracefile namfile

    $ns flush-trace

    close $tracefile

    close $namfile

    exec nam twonodes.nam &

    exit 0

}

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {

    $ns at $val(stop) "\$n$i reset"

}

$ns at $val(stop) "$ns nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"

$ns at $val(stop) "finish"

$ns at $val(stop) "puts \"done\" ; $ns halt"

$ns run
```

'

Answer (score 0):

`EnergyModel` : May be the 'NS-Visual-Trace-Analyser' is confused by the plenty more information in the trace file. Or it isn't meant to deal with the complex output from an "EnergyModel" trace. NAM shows equal transmission in the two cases. Which can also be analyzed with the usual awk and perl scripts. Example, "packets arrival time" .... ( 1,912 lines )

```
$ awk -f tess-Packets.awk twonodes.tr
1.000000000   0
1.004995421   0.00499542
1.115411904   0
1.115411904   0
1.129437799   0.0140259
1.143764325   0.0283524
.
.
16.676762226   0.106707
16.690768753   0.104122
16.704875279   0.101976
16.718961806   0.0998111
```

The "top 20" ns2 awk scripts → `awk-ns2-first.17.tar.gz`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUnRKbmhMdFNyQU0/view?usp=sharing

All ~180 awk, perl scripts for ns2 : `awk#perl#python__scripts-06.2017.tar.gz`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOW9HaHVoaHZzRWs/view?usp=sharing

Other simulation examples with EnergyModel : EnergyModel-examples.tar.gz  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRlZ2WWZmS09IdUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Added six examples → EnergyModel-examples.tar.gz to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me too, and i solved it by disable printing of energy values from c++ to main trace file. Instead i printed energy values to a separate trace file

in cmu-trace.cc

```
if (thisnode) {
        if (thisnode->energy_model()) {
            // log detailed energy consumption
            // total energy and breakdown in idle, sleep, transmit and receive modes
            sprintf(pt_->buffer() + offset,
                "[energy %f ei %.3f es %.3f et %.3f er %.3f] ",
                thisnode->energy_model()->energy(),
                thisnode->energy_model()->ei(),
                thisnode->energy_model()->es(),             
                thisnode->energy_model()->et(),
                thisnode->energy_model()->er());                
        }
        }
```

disable sprintf function.